# Colsums using loop from indices in list in r

Tags: r, list, loops, rowsum

Hello I have a DF with multiple columns all containing numeric values.  My df contains over 200 columns but the sample should do.  I would like to take the values from the list of indices and using them in a RowSums loop so that the list name is the new column and the sums are the combo of indices

```
Main <- c(rep(1, times = 6), rep(2, times = 6))
Feature1 <- sample(1:20, 12, replace = T)
Feature2 <- sample(400:500, 12, replace = T)
Feature3 <- sample(1:5, 12, replace = T)
df.main <- data.frame(Main, Feature1, Feature2, 
Feature3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

```
 Main Feature1 Feature2 Feature3
1     1        6      483        3
2     1        9      405        1
3     1       18      494        5
4     1        7      499        5
5     1       13      436        1
6     1        2      451        3
7     2        4      456        3
8     2       19      442        5
9     2       16      437        2
10    2        4      497        4
11    2        7      497        3
12    2        5      466        1
```

```
list(`Cool Ranch|Cool Chipotle` = c(1L, 4L,), `Trust|Scotia` = c(3L, 
4L))
```

I want my output to look like this

```
   Main Feature1 Feature2 Feature3 cool_ranch trust_scotia
1     1        6      483        3          4          486
2     1        9      405        1          2          406
3     1       18      494        5          6          499
4     1        7      499        5          6          504
5     1       13      436        1          2          437
6     1        2      451        3          4          454
7     2        4      456        3          5          459
8     2       19      442        5          7          447
9     2       16      437        2          4          439
10    2        4      497        4          6          501
11    2        7      497        3          5          500
12    2        5      466        1          3          467
```

I have tried a few things along the same lines as below

```
> sum.test<- apply(df.main, 2, function(i) rowSums[vlist.imps$i])
Error in rowSums[vlist.imps$i] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Comment: Is your expected output values correct.  Maybe you need `df.main[names(vlist.imps)] <- lapply(vlist.imps, function(x) rowSums(df.main[x]))`

Comment: @akrun this appears to be what I was trying to do thank you! I will check the values tomorrow because there are quite a few to go through in this large dataset to make sure.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use loop over the 'vlist.imps', extract the columns of 'df.main' with those index, get the `rowSums` and assign the output back to create new columns

```
df.main[names(vlist.imps)] <- lapply(vlist.imps, function(x) rowSums(df.main[x]))
```